# Have varioref output a \nameref instead of a \ref

Tags: cross-referencing, varioref

According to the varioref package documentation:

> The implementation of `\vref` below produces only a `\ref` when reference
>   and `\label` are on the same page. It will additionally produce one of
>   the strings ‘on the facing page’, ‘on the preceding page’, or ‘on the
>   following page’, if label and reference differ by one and it will
>   produce both `\ref` and `\pageref` when the difference is larger. The word
>   ‘facing’ is used when label and reference both fall onto a double
>   spread. However, if a special page numbering scheme is used instead of
>   the usual arabic numbering (e.g., `\pagenumbering{roman}`) then there
>   will be no distinction between one or many pages off.

I would like to use `\vref` but have it output a `\nameref` instead of a `\ref`. I don't think varioref provides an option for this; is it possible to achieve this in a simple way?

Comment: You should take a look at at the `cleveref` package documentation (cleveref has to be loaded after varioref).

Comment: Please give a specific example of what you have in mind.

Comment: Please give an example of a `\nameref`.

Comment: \section{Introduction}\label{intro} [...] Please see section \nameref{intro} on page \pageref{intro}

Comment: @Mico `\nameref` is provided by the `nameref` package which is part of the `hyperref` bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved what I needed by defining a new command `\xref` as follows:

```
\newcommand{\xref}[1]{\nameref{#1} \vpageref[\unskip]{#1}}
```

This outputs a `\nameref`, and additionally a string similar to 'on page XX' if reference and `\label` are not on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

You can patch the internal `\vr@f` (which should be rather safe I believe):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref,nameref,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% replace \ref with \nameref,
% \patchcmd is provided by the etoolbox package:
\patchcmd\vr@f{\ref}{\nameref}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Foo bar baz}\label{sec:foo}

\newpage

See section \vref{sec:foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Save is relative, after all it is as you say an internal command and not an interface level one (and it will probably change with the next release, thoug with luck your patch is simple enough to survive).